# YAML CSS with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yaml-css

I'd like to use YAML (the CSS framework not the other one!) in Rails.

I'd like to build it into my Rails app so that it's in my asset pipeline.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is fully legitimize closed question. But it googled well on search query asking how to integrate yaml-css in rails. And you search what it is mean you are not aware of https://rails-assets.org/. Other options has drawbacks: holding full copy in application not an option at all, yamlcss gem allow to require only base.scss. So best option use rails-assets gems.